# Can Typescript infer the type of an instance of an extension class instantiated by a method of its base?

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, subclass, type-inference

Consider the following Typescript snippet:

```
class Animal {
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  name: string;

  haveBaby(name: string): ?? return type ?? {
    return new this.constructor(name); // Error
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Gerbil extends Animal {} // etc.

let sorachi = new Cat("Sorachi"); // a: Cat
let sorachiJr = a.haveBaby("Sorachi Jr."); // I want: sorachiJr: Cat
```

Animals can have babies, and a baby should be the same kind of animal as the parent, i.e., should be an instance of the same class as the parent. How do I assign types in this situation, so that Typescript knows that `sorachiJr: Cat`?

*The code snippet above doesn't work.* The line `return new this.constructor(name)` produces the error `[ts] Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.` in VS Code. The only solution I was able to find and understand was replacing `this.constructor(name)` with `(<any>this.constructor)(name)` or `(<any>this).constructor(name)`, but then the type inferred for `sorachiJr` is `any`, too, rather than `Cat`.  I tried casting to `typeof this` rather than `any`, but got the error `[ts] Cannot find name 'this'`.

How can I convince Typescript that having babies is a species-preserving operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preserving the type of the class the method was called on is easy, we just use the polymorphic `this` type. To convince the ts that `constructor` will be a constructor that takes a `string`  and returns an instance the same type as the current class requires a type assertion

```
type AnimalConstructor<T extends Animal> = new (name: string) => T
class Animal {
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    name: string;

    haveBaby(name: string): this  {
        return new (this.constructor as AnimalConstructor<this>)(name); 
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Gerbil extends Animal {} // etc.

let sorachi = new Cat("Sorachi"); // a: Cat
let sorachiJr = sorachi.haveBaby("Sorachi Jr.");
```

**Note** Typescript can't validate the fact that the derived class constructor only expects a single `string` parameter, it might require more or less parameters. This makes this constructor not type safe.