# Typescript Class inference

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Does anyone know how to get the current class in an abstract-generic-class | how to reference the current class like a type "CurrentClass" and not just the abstract class?

reason: i'm writing a small library, that should "infer" the current class without doing "as CurrentClass"

```
abstract class Super {
  public static create(args: keyof CurrentClass) {}
}

class CurrentClass extends Super {}

// to prevent
CurrentClass.create({} as CurrentClass);
```

i searched everywhere, but couldnt find an answer to this, so is it even possible in typescript?

---

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841793/can-typescript-infer-the-type-of-an-instance-of-an-extension-class-instantiated) would solve it, but not for static functions

Update: it seems that [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) is the issue i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual workaround is to add a type parameter to infer the target from the call:

```
abstract class Super {
  s = ""
  public static create<T>(this:new (...a: any[]) => T, args: keyof T) {}
}

class CurrentClass extends Super {
  c = ""
}

// to prevent
CurrentClass.create("c"); // ok
CurrentClass.create("s"); // ok
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgygVwA4FMoEBvAWACgEEMBeBAInoqt2xGQEtZqJgIukUfH3wAeACoA+ABQQAFhzAAuAHb4A7gmkA6XcCUJgKgJ4BtALoBKBDUkJxAGkNQA5soQBrfMYD2AM3trYgBfClDyChQ0DABhbCghFQgY1HQEfAAPCHwVABMMHAIiMkokGwYmcnCKAHoahAgfBFwhADcciAo4hI6U6O1YIRFpelh6SwBuBDqEHw8u+MTk1LABoeyRsHGpmbmgA)

Comment: but this workaround wouldnt give me the keys(/type infomation) from the abstract Super class, right?

Comment: @hasezoey sure it would, that comes from inheritance .. in the example I added keys from both Super and CurentClass. If you don't want keys from Super you can use `Exclude`

Comment: i meant like in the create function i wouldnt have the types of super, because i cant see an "extends" or assignment there

Comment: @hasezoey There are multiple variations of the solution depending on your needs.You could do `create<T extends Super>` if you need access to instance members of super. You will not have access to the statics of `Super` although if we complicate the type a bit more you can gain access to them. Let me know if you have a concrete issue you are having trouble with.

Comment: [this is my current implementation & what i wanted to have](https://gist.github.com/hasezoey/2cb25acdd62605b4d397267e9322f8c2)

Comment: @hasezoey `T` not `keyof T`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgewHYDECuSDGICWyAKATgtIeHAIYC2UAzgDwAqAfDALwwDeMA2gNIwcSGAGsoYBADMYjALoAuGf1kwoADxBQkAE1ox0WXMhgB+GEigA3KIRiKBAXx5iJ0uQG5QkWIlQZseEhEJDa4dEysHPg4mCJMADTwyAYBBMSk5NThLMyeXtAwALIUYgDKCDQA8hBGSBQANgkwAuqaOnouUjKRMJVUOCBNfKwAZDD4FGQ4DfTRsUPMucDAFABGtCCEFNgwmPUUtHoAQgewnMAwMBBoq-UxMAD6ONoAhIobhEIA5p6X17f3WgUawACgAlFwHBcrjc7pgYBsKLh4QcwFhdoQoEioExVBotLoYCdaFBmCCQAALHC0RQWADuMBBADoWRRFBQkGAeLIIWxWIwYIlLA00FBFL4UrVghkcOFimUKlBqrUZoxEgAiJ7adWLCHnS6XTDIDYwbQIeEcekwSnUkHC+qisG-A0UOkUAam81MoGgp3LA0wTEgNCEYRmzDOqFQoA