# Typescript Class inference with statics

Tags: typescript, inheritance, type-inference

```js
import { FilterQuery } from "mongodb";

abstract class Base<T extends Base<any>> {
    public static async findOne<T extends Base<any>>(
        this: new (...a: any[]) => T,
        query: FilterQuery<T>
    ): Promise<T> {
        console.log(this.getSomeString()); // currently: "getSomeString" dosnt exists on type "new (...a: any[]) => T"
        // already tried "typeof T" - because "typeof" is not allowed on generics
        // already tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358194/8944059 's static solution
        // already tried "T" - which makes "this: any"
        // and i tried various other things, which resulted in "await SomeExtendingClass" cannot be assigned to "this"

        // Edit for @jcalz
        console.log(this.someProtectedMethod()); // error "someProtectedMethod" does not exists on type "this"

        return undefined;
    }

    public static getSomeString(): string {
        this.someProtectedMethod(); // this would work
        return "Hello";
    }

    // Edit for @jcalz
    protected static someProtectedMethod() {
        return "hello2";
    }
}

class SomeExtendingClass extends Base<SomeExtendingClass> {
    public someValue: string;
}

(async () => {
    await SomeExtendingClass.findOne({ someValue: "hi" });
})();
```

Goal is to have all statics in `this` while being able to call it with `new this(...args)` and while having all keys of (Parent class) insert-able into `query` and without having to remove `abstract`

Already tried:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58037767/8944059
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358194/8944059 's static solution

PS: i dont understand most of the magic of typescript types, that is why i'm asking...

PPS: [here is the project i would need it](https://github.com/hasezoey/typegoose-v2/blob/dc29eee627e9f1ac77845da14b5206b3ad2f97c0/src/baseModel.ts#L37-L46)

Comment: Can you change `findOne()'s` `this` parameter type to `Pick<typeof Base, keyof typeof Base> & (new (...a: any[]) => T)`?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, this done it, but do you know how to include `protected` functions / values?

Comment: I don't know; can you edit your code to be a [mcve] so I can test it myself?  It's possible you can just use `typeof Base & (new (...a: any[]) => T)` but I'd have to see a full [mcve] to know if it works.  The issue with `private` and `protected` members is they are intentionally hidden from `keyof`, see [microsoft/TypeScript#13543](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13543)

Comment: @jcalz i added an example method & how i would call it

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks to [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)*

His answer was to replace

`new (...a: any[]) => T`

with

`Pick<typeof Base, keyof typeof Base> & (new (...a: any[]) => T)`,

this fixed it for me *mostly*

what i found is that this does not include `protected` values/functions

<sub>*this question will be edited if an answer to the `protected` sub-question can be found*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Your example code doesn't show why you need any `this` parameter at all.  For example, the following code works even with `protected` static methods.  The default type of `this` is just `typeof Base`:

```
import { FilterQuery } from "mongodb";
abstract class Base<T extends Base<any>> {
    public static async findOne<T extends Base<any>>(
        query: FilterQuery<T>
    ): Promise<T> {
        console.log(this.getSomeString()); 
        console.log(this.someProtectedMethod()); 
        return undefined!; // <-- not a Promise
    }

    public static getSomeString(): string {
        return "Hello";
    }
    protected static someProtectedMethod() {
        return "hello2";
    }
}
class SomeExtendingClass extends Base<SomeExtendingClass> {
    public someValue: string = "123"; // needs initialization
}
(async () => {
    await SomeExtendingClass.findOne({ someValue: "hi" });
})();
```

If the above doesn't suffice for your use case, please edit your example code to show some places where it breaks.  Presumably there's some reason you needed to add a `this` parameter in the first place; what's the reason?

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMWAGxgUygRQK7YCecAvnAGZQQhwBEIEAdgOYQAmARrQNwBQvAQw4BnGFAEBjeBLQDhwuACE5mADwAVOJgAeWRmwXLhagY0IA+c4l5xbcMHg5pgEuKIEwXcOYUavywPoA8oxqmjp6BkoqqqYW5gAUNnYpAI4EUIQAXCjoWLgZhBrmybYAlDkAClQgwMbF1ikpEkzCEGiYAHRoEMwJMAAWdZ3MmDAAytSY42KBfWVlfE12LYxtHd29-UPCnW0gmNUQWFKYbACyYwPsCQtLy3BQY3hQjHCMeGhoAIT3tiSleyOZyudyeVyjCZTGZQOa3HKiWEsRoPJ4wF5vWgACUwXwgPEBAJSYCoJywbDcMA8Xn2h1JmFOFyuNzKKOWaIxdAGuJ6ACYCSkAQDeDI5ApJgcAKK6TD6OYAYVk8i0Mv0hhiEsw0siCqVwisCEBDicNKmADUBGgCAjZsiALx0ACMvIAzDw4AB6D3vTBnBSBYCeS3AABe1KYvABmu1srYurFnQCwVCCQ+X2+i093ogAGsBIR+EA)

---

Edit: if you need `this` to be constructible with zero args inside `findOne()`, and not allow `findOne()` to be called on a class that isn't constructible that way, you could possibly do this:

```
abstract class Base<T extends Base<any>> {
    public static async findOne<T extends Base<any>>(
        this: typeof Base & (new () => any),
        query: FilterQuery<T>
    ): Promise<T> {
        console.log(this.getSomeString());
        console.log(this.someProtectedMethod());
        new this();
        return null!;
    }
    public static getSomeString(): string {
        return "Hello";
    }
    protected static someProtectedMethod() {
        return "hello2";
    }
}

Base.findOne(null!); // error, abstract

class SomeExtendingClass extends Base<SomeExtendingClass> {
    public someValue: string = "123"; // needs initialization
}
SomeExtendingClass.findOne(null!); // okay

class InvalidExtendingClass extends Base<InvalidExtendingClass> {
    constructor(x: string) {
        super();
    }
}
InvalidExtendingClass.findOne(null!); // error, requires an argument
```

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-HIknjKod-vnIeE6OT5ns2sNmI8FJoAltOW2cwNasdjCHgBRQGiYoDrwN4Hkej7MKe8gToEU42owdrztwTauu6nqYr0wCYgopjeFAzB4ICjB+rwCQ+H49RNC+dgCNUAgdnAQ4PmOiGTtOCRIAWxalpgOS0BktCkE8A51OB-BAA)

If you have other requirements (like allowing different constructor arguments for subclasses) then let me know.  Good luck again!

Comment: "If the above doesn't suffice for your use case" that is why i included the mongodb type, without defining "this" you dont have type support for all the values defined in the inherited class, in this case it is `someValue` in `.findOne({ someValue: "hi" })`, PS: i mean without doing `.findOne<SomeExtendingClass>()` and just having it infered from the "this"

Comment: Sorry for the late response, didnt see the edit - "initialization" is a no-go in my use-case, and otherwise, i get the error i mentioned already "The "this" context of Type "typeof SomeClass" cannot be assigned to the type "typeof Base"" - this might relate to some other complex types i (have to) use

Comment: "Your example code doesn't show why you need any this" sorry, but i linked to the repo i would need | use it in, which has a constructor with arguments

Comment: Initialization is just a type safety concern; if you don't want to do it, it doesn't affect the rest of the answer  (but you *should* do it, or make the property optional.  uninitialized properties are a source of bugs).

Comment: An external repo doesn't really count as a [mcve], unfortunately.  External links are good for convenience but not if they contain substantive information needed for the question.  All pertinent information should be in the text of the question as suggested in the guidelines for [ask] (and in [answer] also, fwiw).

Comment: i didnt include it in the "minimal reproducible example", because this was not the question (at least i think so), and "uninitialized properties are a source of bugs)" they are set with and decorator (default) and otherwise in the constructor, this here was just for demonstration

Comment: and "<-- not a Promise" was just a copy-paste "error", because while i was testing setting the "this" parameter, the function was not finished

Comment: Okay, well at this point I've given you all the ways I know to deal with this issue, all of which work for the example code posted in the question itself.  So I think I'm probably done here.  Good luck coding!

Comment: thanks for answering the question so quick & sticking through to some "extra" - my "solution" was at the end, to not use the protected functions (make public / out of the class)